# How can the make function take three parameters?

Tags: function, go

The function `make` is describe like this:

```
func make(Type, size IntegerType) Type
```

When we use `make` for slicing sometimes it shows like:

```
make([]int, 0, 10)
```

So my question is:

How can the `make` function take three parameters? The `size IntegerType` is not Vararg. I'm confused...

Answer (score 13):

The `make` function is one of a bunch of built-in functions that are allowed to do things that you cannot achieve (at least not cleanly and easily) in your Go code.
It has a number of overloaded forms for creating maps, channels and slices (see 
https://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels) :

Your confusion probably stems from https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#make which shows `make` as having the signature `func make(Type, size IntegerType) Type`.
If you look closer in that section, you would also see an indication that `make` can have a third argument:

> Slice: The size specifies the length. The capacity of the slice is
>    equal to its length. **A second integer argument may be provided to
>    specify a different capacity**; it must be no smaller than the length,
>    so make([]int, 0, 10) allocates a slice of length 0 and capacity 10.

You can also notice that `make` can also be used without its integer argument:

> Map: An initial allocation is made according to the size but the
>   resulting map has length 0. **The size may be omitted**, in which case a
>   small starting size is allocated.
>
> Channel: The channel's buffer is initialized with the specified buffer capacity. If zero, **or the size is omitted**, the channel is unbuffered.

Answer (score 7):

The `make()` function is not a regular function, is a builtin function being part of the language specification. What you see in the `builtin` package ([`builtin.make()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#make)) is only for documentation purposes. That is not the actual signature of the function. The 3rd optional parameter is the **capacity**, which may only be provided when you're creating a slice.

It's described in the spec: [Making slices, maps and channels:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels)

```
make(T, n)       slice      slice of type T with length n and capacity n
make(T, n, m)    slice      slice of type T with length n and capacity m
```

And also mentioned at [Slice types:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types)

> A new, initialized slice value for a given element type `T` is made using the built-in function `make`, which takes a slice type and parameters specifying the length **and optionally the capacity**. A slice created with make always allocates a new, hidden array to which the returned slice value refers. That is, executing
>
> ```
> make([]T, length, capacity)
> ```
>
> produces the same slice as allocating an array and slicing it, so these two expressions are equivalent:
>
> ```
> make([]int, 50, 100)
> new([100]int)[0:50]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The function `make` [is a builtin function](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels). The function has several features not available to other functions. One is that it takes a variable number arguments as you noted. Another is that the first argument is a type.

The [function definition `func make(Type, size IntegerType) Type`](https://godoc.org/builtin#make) is for documentation purposes only.  It is not the actual definition of the function.