# Data structure to store key-value pairs with duplicate keys

Tags: dictionary, go, slice

Which data structure can I use in Go to store key-value pairs with duplicate keys? For eg:

```
key | value
 1     one
 2     two
 1     three
```

and If I try to fetch values corresponding to key `1` I should get an array of values `one,three`. I tries using map, but it gives me only 1 value.

```
mapy := make(map[int]interface{})
mapy[1] = "one"
mapy[2] = "two"
mapy[1] = "three"
x := mapy[1]
fmt.Println(x)

output: three
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### With slice value type

`map` is a good choice if you need fast lookup, but since you want to store multiple values for the same key, that warrants for a slice as the value type:

```
m := map[int][]interface{}{}
m[1] = append(m[1], "one")
m[2] = append(m[2], "two")
m[1] = append(m[1], "three")
fmt.Println(m[1])
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ssMRu0Prad)):

```
[one three]
```

Note that using this `map` is a little less convenient, as when you want to add a new value you don't (can't) just assign it but you have to append to the existing slice associated with the key, and you have to assign back the (potentially) new slice.

To ease this "pain", you may create your own type and provide helper methods to support different operations on the map. This is also true for the subsequent alternatives, so being a little more verbose does not necessarily mean you have to struggle with it.

#### With pointer to slice value type

Note that you could avoid having to reassign the new slice if you would store pointers in the map, for example:

```
m := map[int]*[]interface{}{}
m[1] = &[]interface{}{}
m[2] = &[]interface{}{}

s := m[1]
*s = append(*s, "one")
s = m[2]
*s = append(*s, "two")
s = m[1]
*s = append(*s, "three")
fmt.Println(m[1])
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/2O7N3dD9sW)):

```
&[one three]
```

You still have to assign back the slice returned by `append()`, but not to a map key but to the pointed value (acquired from / stored in the map).

But as you can see, handling it is more hassle, but may be more efficient if you add new elements frequently. Also note that since zero value for any pointer type is `nil`, before you could add an element for a key, you first have to initialize it with a pointer to an existing, non-`nil` slice (but if you create your own type, you can hide this check and initialization).

#### With map as value type

Previous solutions (with slices in keys) are good, but if you also have to support frequent removal operation, they lag behind, as whenever you have to remove an element, you index the map to get the slice, and you have to search this slice and remove the element from it (and removing from a slice includes slice header update and copying subsequent elements to 1-less indices). If this slice is not sorted, this is a linear search and so it has `O(n)` complexity (where `n` is the number of elements associated with the same key, not the number of keys in the map). May not be acceptable depending on your case.

To support fast element removal, you may keep the value slices sorted, and so finding the removable element in them is `O(log(n))` complexity – acceptable in most cases.

An even faster solution may use another map (as a set, see [example #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30452518/1705598) and [example #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39249045/1705598)) as the value type, which will be `O(1)` complexity for removals too. Cool. It could look like this:

```
m := map[int]map[interface{}]bool{}
m[1] = map[interface{}]bool{}
m[2] = map[interface{}]bool{}

m[1]["one"] = true
m[2]["two"] = true
m[1]["three"] = true
fmt.Println(m[1])
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/VGN3NMT1SP)):

```
map[one:true three:true]
```

Just as with the pointer-to-slice value type, you first have to initialize a value for a key with a non-`nil` map before you can actually "add" values to it. Hide this by creating your own type and adding methods.

Comment: Thanks. I agree  I will have to append to the slice but I hope this is not an in-efficient way of doing things?

Comment: @love2code As long as you don't have to frequently remove elements, this is fine and may be one of the fastest solution.

Comment: Can we make a slice of maps without specifying the length ? I tried `scores := make([]int, 50)` but I dont have the length fixed.

Comment: @love2code You could just create a 0-length slice: `make([]int, 0)`, and `append()` will automatically increase its size (by reallocating a new one and copying the old). But if you want to pre-allocate space, then `make()`  may take an [optional 3rd argument being the capacity](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36349094/1705598), so for example: `make([]int, 0, 50)`

Comment: I tried this `regionsArray := make(map[int]string , 0)` , `regionMap :=  make(map[int]string)  regionMap[1] = "USA"` and then `regionsArray = append(regionsArray , regionMap)` gave me `first argument to append must be slice; have map[int]string`

Comment: ok `regionsArray := make([]map[int]string , 0)` this worked. I was not making a slice of maps. Thanks!

Comment: @love2code Because your `regionsArray` is **not** an array or slice, it's a `map`! You can only `append()` to slices, but not to maps.